# Display whole number for time diff using conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have a dataset where I would like to create a new column that contains the month difference using dates.

**Data**

```
reg         in      
9/1/2021    9/30/2021       
9/8/2021    11/22/2021      
9/8/2021    1/13/2022
10/1/2021   10/15/2021  
11/2/2022   5/1/2023
```

**Desired**

```
reg         in          new_month
9/1/2021    9/30/2021   0   
9/8/2021    11/22/2021  2   
9/8/2021    1/13/2022   4   
10/1/2021   10/15/2021  0
11/2/2022   5/1/2023    6
```

**Doing**

```
from datetime import datetime


df['new_month'] = df['in'].dt.to_period('M').astype(int) - 
df['reg'].dt.to_period('M').astype(int)
```

However I wish for the output to be in whole numbers, and if it is under a month, the result will be 0. Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
df['new_column'] = (df.reg - df.in)
```

Comment: thank you - I think the syntax has to be df['reg']... will try

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is to start by finding the difference of the days between the two dates and then perform floor division by 30 to get the amount of months.

```
from datetime import datetime

def days_between(d1, d2):
    d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, "%Y-%m-%d")
    x = abs((d2 - d1).days)
    return x//30
```